# How would one make units work with a variable of unknown magnitude?

Tags: units

So, right now, I am working on setting various quantities up as functions of R. R will be varying later on, so right now I just have it set to the variable radius. It's breaking my dimensional analysis later on in the notebook though, because Mathematica assumes `radius` has units, when it should just be a scalar. Is there a better way to say the following so that I can have dimensional analysis work in the meanwhile?

```
R = Quantity[radius, "Meters"];
```

This is the output:

```
UnitSimplify[
 Sqrt[1 - (1.408969*10^6 radius^2)/(
   1.380123*10^7 + 1.408969*10^6 radius^2)] (Quantity[
    7.67349*10^-12 radius^2, (("Amperes")^2 ("Meters")^2 (
     "Seconds")^2 ("Teslas")^2)/("Kilograms")])]
```

It should just be in Joules! But, when I set R to a quantity, like so:

```
R = Quantity[1, "Meters"];
```

I get such a pretty result:

```
{7.30945*10^-12 J}
```

I think I need to strip the units off radius. I tried Quantity Magnitude, but Mathematica wasn't a fan.

Comment: Probably if you [edit] to include a **minimum working example of your code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)** we could see how its breaking a suggest a solution. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: `MapAt[UnitSimplify, expr, -1]` instead of `UnitSimplify[expr]`.

Comment: I am confused. In your sample expression `R` is never used, so its value cannot matter to the final result. What expression are you actually evaluating when you obtain the numerical result you show?

Comment: `a = Solve[lorentz*m0*tempv/(q*B) == R, lorentz][[2]]
T = ((lorentz /. a) - 1)*m0*c^2 // N`

Comment: Perhaps you can make use of the available dimensionless unit: `Quantity[radius, "DimensionlessUnit"]`?

Comment: What happens if you do something like `R = radius Quantity[1, "Meters"];`?

Answer (score 2):

**General Remarks**

`UnitSimplify` is expecting an expression with head `Quantity`, and the factor before the quantity prevents the evaluation. We have for instance:

```
UnitConvert[a Quantity[2, "Inches"]]
(* UnitConvert[a (Quantity[2, "Inches"])] *)

UnitConvert[Quantity[2, "Inches"]]
(* Quantity[127/2500, "Meters"] *)
```

Note that the expression `a Quantity[2, "Inches"]` does not evaluate itself to a `Quantity` object:

```
a Quantity[2, "Inches"]
(* a (Quantity[2, "Inches"]) *)
```

because `a` is not `NumericQ`. On the contrary, this returns a `Quantity`:

```
(1 + Sqrt[2]) Quantity[2, "Inches"]
(* Quantity[2 (1 + Sqrt[2]), "Inches"] *)
```

Some spelunking (`` <<GeneralUtilities`; PrintDefinitions[Quantity] ``) shows the definition yielding this behavior. It starts with

```
Quantity /: Condition[HoldPattern[Times][...]
```

---

**OP's question**

Back to OP's question, a possible approach is to make the non-`NumericQ` factor of the expression enter the magnitude of the quantity. This can be done as follows:

```
makeQuantity[HoldPattern[Times[fact_, q_Quantity ?QuantityQ]]] := 
        Quantity[fact QuantityMagnitude[q], QuantityUnit[q]]
```

Taking OP's expression

```
expr = Sqrt[1 - (1.408969*10^6 radius^2)/(1.380123*10^7 + 1.408969*10^6 radius^2)] *
    Quantity[
          7.67349*10^-12 radius^2, 
          (("Amperes")^2 ("Meters")^2 ("Seconds")^2 ("Teslas")^2)/("Kilograms")
    ]
```

we get the expected simplification after processing:

```
makeQuantity[expr]
```

[image]

```
UnitSimplify[%]
```

[image]

This returns the mentioned result for the special case `radius = 1`:

```
% /. radius -> 1
(* Quantity[7.30944*10^-12, "Joules"] *)
```

The pattern I used for the definition of `makeQuantity` is a simple one, it may need to be enhanced depending on what the use is.